# Is it possible to pass any other columns after the where clause in select statement Cassandra

Tags: select, primary-key, cassandra, where-clause, cql

I have been trying to retrieve data from Cassandra database using this command:

```
 select A_NO from Activity where CALL_TYPE IN ('MOC');//here CALL_TYPE is not the row id
```

But its showing :

```
Expected key 'KEY' to be present in where clause for 'Activity'
```

Is it not possible in cassandra to filter the data with the help of a non-primary key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this directly on a vanilla column family. Cassandra by default only let's you query on key's or a key range. You can accomplish  this by creating a secondary index on a column

You would run a CQL query like this to create two indexes:

```
cqlsh> CREATE INDEX state_key ON users (state);
cqlsh> CREATE INDEX birth_year_key ON users (birth_year);
```

And then queried like this:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM users
 ... WHERE gender='f' AND
 ...  state='TX' AND
...  birth_year='1968';
```

[Here is more on Secondary indexes.](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/ddl/indexes#about-secondary-indexes)

[Here is the documentation on using CQL for this.](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/dml/using_cql#indexing-a-column)

Comment: Make sure you mark the answer as solved so someone else who comes by will know this is correct. Thanks!